# Regex negative lookbehind and negative lookahead with composite string

Tags: regex

I have a list of ingredients and I need to highlight its allergen. However, there are some exceptions that need to be ignored. My regex is not ignoring composite strings (string with multiple words separated with space, e.g. Almond Milk).

In the example, I want to highlight **MILK**, **EGGS**, **RICE** and **BUTTER**. However, I want to ignore *RICE MILK* and *GARLIC BUTTER*, as shown below.

Beef **Eggs**(76%)(beef, cheese, rice milk, pork, **milk**), Seasoning (8%)(Thyme, basil, **eggs**, rosemary, tarragon, savoury **butter**, marjoram, oregano, and **rice** bay leaf), Provencal Sauce Water(16%)(Herbes de Provence, celery, chicken broth, **butter**, barley, lupin, garlic butter, and lemon juice)

My code on regex 101 => [Example](https://regex101.com/r/yEPEkc/1)

```
(?<!rice milk|garlic butter)(?<=milk|eggs|butter|rice)|(?!rice milk|garlic butter)(?=milk|eggs|butter|rice)
```

Comment: Do the answers below help? If not, please add your code to the question and provide feedback via a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest different approach, by splitting regex logic by each word:

```
(?:(?<!rice )milk|(?<!garlic )butter|eggs|rice(?! milk))
```

Explanation:

`(?:..)` - non capturing group

`(?<!rice )milk` - match `milk`, but asser that what preceeds is not `rice`  (to exclude `rice milk`) - other regex parts also follow same approach

`|` - alternation operator

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hwj1aJ/1)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for. However, I have made few modifications because I am interested only in the words limits. Thanks.  

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s99F4P/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could match what you don't want, in this case `rice milk` and `garlic butter` and use a capture group what you do want using an alternation `|`

```
\b(?:rice milk|garlic butter)\b|\b(milk|eggs|rice|butter)\b
```

The values of group 1 are highlighted in green in the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0B6O7K/1)

Comment: Nice use of groups to consume unwanted strings :) and almost twice more performant than mine .

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Thanks, it is an option to get what you want but maybe the OP only wants matches. In that case, your pattern will be the one to pick.